# Simulink resets arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, servo, matlab

I am working on servo motors control through serial communication protocol, I am sending data from Simulink to arduino and vice versa, The problem I am getting is that once I open Simulink Servo motors start turning while no command is sent or received from both, I tought that Simulink is initializing (reseting) arduino, so I decided to add a capacitor between Gnd & reset (I also tried with a resistor between 5v & reset), It actually works when I try to use Arduino IDE, Arduino is not reseting, but When i use it with Simulink it doesn't make change, Servo motors still turning randomly (I think that when I start or close simulation, Servo Are going to their initial position, I am not sure). I tried to add initial Position in Setup() function but in vain, It doesn't make sens!
I tried using different arduino cards (MEGA, ESP32...Etc.) but in vain.

Does anyone have an idea about how to figure out this problem?
Here is Simulink control code : & Arduino code :

```
#include <SCServo.h>
SCSCL sc;


//Estructura Union
typedef union {
  float number;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
} valor;
valor velocidad;

unsigned long timeold;
int vel = 0;
float value;
void setup() {

  Serial1.begin(1000000);
  sc.pSerial = &Serial1;
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Pregunta si tenemos un dato a recibir
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    value = recepcion();
  }

  //Transforma el valor del voltaje (0-5) a velocidad
  vel = map(value, 0, 5, 0, 1023);
  //Activa el motor dirección Backward con la velocidad
  sc.WritePos(3,  value, 0);

  velocidad.number = sc.ReadPos(3);

  Serial.write('V');
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Serial.write(velocidad.bytes[i]);
  }
  Serial.write('\n');
  delay(50);
}



//Recibir Flotante
float recepcion() {
  int i;
  valor buf;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    buf.bytes[i] = Serial.read();
  return buf.number;
}
//Función para la lectura del encoder
```

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: first thing to try is to connect Simulink without sending any data at all

Comment: I tried to use Simulink to receive Servo motor angle from arduino, it works great, the servo is not turning randomly, I am getting the servo motor angle in real time. but when I start sending from simulink, the servo motor starts to turn to max & the min angle!

Comment: sounds like a software issue

Comment: Without knowing what code you're running on your arduino or what you're actually trying to do (or what this "simulink" thing is you're talking about) we will be hard pressed to help you.

Comment: Did you check your hardware handshake lines? AFAIK one of them is used to reset the Arduino.

Comment: I added The simulink control code @Majenko

Comment: @thebusybee actually, I have no idea about how to this, I google it but I found nothing about the handshake lines for arduino!

Comment: @jsotola seems to be like that but I can't figure out what is i t

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/our-blog-1/reading-serial-on-the-arduino-27

Comment: I don't know but it seems to work now! I just added a delay(100) after the serial.available() loop  & it works, anyone can explain this for me pleasE